# While updating the badge count as coming from the background state to foreground, the data fetched from core data is faulty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, chat, magicalrecord

I am developing a chat application. So, I have a chat list screen in it. Once the app is sent to the background and it receives a lots of, say around 20 messages, in that state, then when I open the app again and the badge count for the number of unread messages starts updating, my app crashes. This is the log I am getting:

entity: ContactObject; id: 0x7b7d7a40 x-coredata://F4F84B12-9611-42EF-A00C-40CA8ED7D8C0/ContactObject/p71 ; data: fault

[image]

I am using Magical records. I have tried setting the number of fetch requests as I thought may be there were too many fetch requests made at once, gave delays and many more things but nothing works so far. The same thing is working fine if the app stays in the foreground throughout. I am attaching the screen for reference. Please help me out guys.And I am working in Swift.

Comment: Can you include the code around the crash and the code that relates to that area of your app?

Comment: let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.fromUserJid == %@",bareId)

  let localContactsArray : NSArray = ContactObject.MR_findAllWithPredicate(predicate)!

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   userCell.distance.text = localContactsArray[0].messageBody as String })


it crashes inside the dispatch block, gives the nill unwrapping error....but nothing is nill, when I print the log for the objects I get 

<NSManagedObject: 0x7b61adc0> (entity: ContactObject; id: 0x7b7d7a40 <x-coredata://F4F84B12-9611-42EF-A00C-40CA8ED7D8C0/ContactObject/p71> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: Does localContactsArray definitely get populated? And with the correct data?

Comment: Yes, its some memory management rule of core data that it does not fetch the complete data even if the data is there. Anyways its working fine in the foreground state. So, the data must be correct only.